# Messed up my MYSQL on CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos

Had some problems with sshd which has now been resolved however I've sent a few hours till 4AM trying to fix some permission problems which ended up messing all ownerships and permissions.

MariaDB is not failing to start.

I've posted below the output of the status
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. I tried to reinstall mysql, maybe it will solve my problem, but there is no difference.

```
[root@sentora /]# systemctl status mariadb.service
* mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-06-17 14:05:24 UTC; 7s ago
  Process: 2039 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Apr 15 18:57:22 sentora mysqld_safe[188]: 170415 18:57:22 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
Apr 17 00:29:02 sentora mysqld_safe[188]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 183: 12292 Killed           ...ull
Apr 17 00:29:03 sentora mysqld_safe[188]: 170417 00:29:03 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
Apr 17 00:29:03 sentora mysqld_safe[188]: 170417 00:29:03 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
Apr 17 00:29:09 sentora mysqld_safe[188]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 183: 22326 Killed           ...ull
Apr 17 00:29:09 sentora mysqld_safe[188]: 170417 00:29:09 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
Apr 17 00:29:10 sentora mysqld_safe[188]: 170417 00:29:09 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
Apr 17 00:29:15 sentora mysqld_safe[188]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 183: 22382 Killed           ...ull
Apr 17 00:29:16 sentora mysqld_safe[188]: 170417 00:29:16 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
Apr 17 00:29:16 sentora mysqld_safe[188]: 170417 00:29:16 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
Jun 15 08:19:10 sentora systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB database server...
Jun 15 08:24:10 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.
Jun 15 08:24:10 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jun 15 08:24:10 sentora systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB database server.
Jun 15 08:24:10 sentora systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jun 15 08:24:10 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mariadb-prepare-db-dir[1192]: touch: cannot touch '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb...ed
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mariadb-prepare-db-dir[1192]: chown: cannot access '/var/log/mariadb/mariad...ed
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mariadb-prepare-db-dir[1192]: chmod: cannot access '/var/log/mariadb/mariad...ed
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mysqld_safe[1220]: 170615 23:31:36 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/maria...og'.
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mysqld_safe[1220]: touch: cannot touch '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log': Pe...nied
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mysqld_safe[1220]: chmod: cannot access '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log': P...nied
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mysqld_safe[1220]: 170615 23:31:36 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon wit...ysql
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mysqld_safe[1220]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 139: /var/log/mariadb/maria...nied
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mysqld_safe[1220]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 183: /var/log/mariadb/maria...nied
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mysqld_safe[1220]: touch: cannot touch '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log': Pe...nied
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mysqld_safe[1220]: chown: cannot access '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log': P...nied
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora mysqld_safe[1220]: chmod: cannot access '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log': P...nied
Jun 15 23:31:36 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 15 23:31:37 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 15 23:31:37 sentora systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jun 15 23:31:37 sentora systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jun 15 23:31:37 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mariadb-prepare-db-dir[1418]: touch: cannot touch '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb...ed
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mariadb-prepare-db-dir[1418]: chown: cannot access '/var/log/mariadb/mariad...ed
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mariadb-prepare-db-dir[1418]: chmod: cannot access '/var/log/mariadb/mariad...ed
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mysqld_safe[1446]: 170615 23:34:54 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/maria...og'.
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mysqld_safe[1446]: touch: cannot touch '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log': Pe...nied
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mysqld_safe[1446]: chmod: cannot access '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log': P...nied
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mysqld_safe[1446]: 170615 23:34:54 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon wit...ysql
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mysqld_safe[1446]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 139: /var/log/mariadb/maria...nied
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mysqld_safe[1446]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 183: /var/log/mariadb/maria...nied
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mysqld_safe[1446]: touch: cannot touch '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log': Pe...nied
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mysqld_safe[1446]: chown: cannot access '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log': P...nied
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora mysqld_safe[1446]: chmod: cannot access '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log': P...nied
Jun 15 23:34:54 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 15 23:34:55 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 15 23:34:55 sentora systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jun 15 23:34:55 sentora systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jun 15 23:34:55 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Jun 15 23:35:50 sentora systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jun 15 23:35:51 sentora mysqld_safe[1675]: 170615 23:35:51 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/maria...og'.
Jun 15 23:35:51 sentora mysqld_safe[1675]: 170615 23:35:51 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon wit...ysql
Jun 15 23:35:52 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 15 23:35:52 sentora systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jun 15 23:35:52 sentora systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jun 15 23:35:52 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Jun 15 23:36:58 sentora systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jun 15 23:36:59 sentora mysqld_safe[1906]: 170615 23:36:59 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/maria...og'.
Jun 15 23:36:59 sentora mysqld_safe[1906]: 170615 23:36:59 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon wit...ysql
Jun 15 23:36:59 sentora mysqld_safe[1906]: 170615 23:36:59 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/...nded
Jun 15 23:36:59 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 15 23:37:00 sentora systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jun 15 23:37:00 sentora systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jun 15 23:37:00 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Jun 15 23:41:43 sentora systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jun 15 23:41:43 sentora mysqld_safe[2144]: 170615 23:41:43 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/maria...og'.
Jun 15 23:41:43 sentora mysqld_safe[2144]: 170615 23:41:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon wit...ysql
Jun 15 23:41:46 sentora systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
Jun 15 23:52:23 sentora systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB database server...
Jun 15 23:52:24 sentora systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB database server.
Jun 17 01:58:56 sentora systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB database server...
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora mysqld_safe[238]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 887: touch: command not found
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora mysqld_safe[238]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 888: chown: command not found
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora mysqld_safe[238]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 889: chmod: command not found
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora mysqld_safe[238]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 892: date: command not found
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora mysqld_safe[238]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 135: date: command not found
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jun 17 01:58:57 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Jun 17 02:04:20 sentora systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jun 17 02:04:20 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Jun 17 02:04:20 sentora systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jun 17 02:04:20 sentora systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jun 17 02:04:20 sentora systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

Comment: what exactly happened to the host? things like `touch: command not found and date: command not found` point to something far more dodgy than just some permissions getting broken. is this a production box?

Comment: Post output of `echo "$PATH"`